# How to make SQL intersection with table-valued parameter?

Tags: sql-server, intersect, table-valued-parameters

I need to make an intersection and get the `variantID` in common; from a list of parameter pairs `(optionID,valueID)`.

Example: for a given list that has 2 items in it:

- optionID = 16 and valueID = 1
- optionID = 17 and valueID = 4

I wrote below queries manually:

```
select * 
from tbl_VariantValues
where optionID = 16 and valueID = 1 and productID = 399 

select * 
from tbl_VariantValues
where optionID = 17 and valueID = 4 and productID = 399
```

I'm getting these results:

```
productID  variantID  optionID  valueID
---------------------------------------
399        11         16        1
399        12         16        1
399        13         16        1
399        14         16        1
399        15         16        1

productID  variantID  optionID  valueID
---------------------------------------
399        13         17        4
399        19         17        4
```

As I need `variantID` only, with intersection:

```
select variantID 
from tbl_VariantValues
where optionID = 16 
  and valueID = 1 
  and productID = 319 

intersect 

select variantID 
from tbl_VariantValues
where optionID = 17 
  and valueID = 4 
  and productID = 319
```

I'm getting desired result variantID: 13

The problem is I want to do above query programatically as there can be more items in the `tvp` list. Is it possible?

I tried to write below query but don't know where and how to put intersect:

```
create procedure [dbo].[getVariantID]
    (@list OptionValueList readonly)
as
begin 
    declare @UseTVP int
    set @UseTVP = (select count(*) from @list) 

    select variantID
    from dbo.tbl_VariantValues
    where (optionID = (select C.OptionID from @list C) 
      and valueID = (select C.OptionID, C.ValueID from @list C)
       or @UseTVP = 0)
    intersect
end
```

`@UseTVP` is the count of the tvp items, I need a logic of intersect usage here to merge the tables. Or is there other way to do this?

Comment: What you've asked is not clear to me. Is there any specific reason that you don't get `optionID`, `valueID`  and `productID` as input parameters inside your stored procedure?

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz As there will be n rows in `tvp` list there will be n different `optionID`, `valueID` pairs to make where clauses; Which means that the select queries in sp will be n pieces, and need to put `intersect` in between, in order to get `variantID`. But couldn't run it. I have syntax error..

Comment: I've updated my answer, if its not fulfilling what you've desired could you please leave a comment under my answer? Maybe I could edit it to help you. Thanks.

Comment: `@UseTVP is the count of the tvp items, I need a logic of intersect usage here to merge the tables.` As you've mentioned in your question @UseTVP is an integer that holds count of the tvp records. But what do you mean by 'merge the tables'? You are trying to merge result with what? What do you mean by this line: `valueID=(SELECT C.OptionID, C.ValueID FROM @list C) OR @UseTVP = 0)` Its totally unclear

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz Simply I want to put intersect between tables, sorry if I coudn't be more clear I tried to explain with an example. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Are you trying to join `@list` with `tbl_VariantValues`? Is @Squirrel answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is use Dynamic SQL to create the query with multiple intersect operator.

Or just use `JOIN` on VariantValues with the OptionValue. Then use `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` to make user all the OptionValue are matches

```
; with 
--  generate sample table tbl_VariantValues
tbl_VariantValues as
(
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 11, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 12, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 13, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 14, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 15, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all

    select  productID = 399, variantID = 13, optionID = 17, valueID = 4 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 14, optionID = 17, valueID = 4 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 19, optionID = 17, valueID = 4 union all

    select  productID = 399, variantID = 13, optionID = 18, valueID = 5 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 15, optionID = 18, valueID = 5 union all
    select  productID = 399, variantID = 19, optionID = 18, valueID = 5
),
--  your OptionValue sample
OptionValueList  as
(
    select  productID = 399, optionID = 16, valueID = 1 union all
    select  productID = 399, optionID = 17, valueID = 4 union all
    select  productID = 399, optionID = 18, valueID = 5
)
--  the query
select  v.variantID
from    tbl_VariantValues v
        inner join OptionValueList o    on  v.productID = o.productID
                                       and  v.optionID  = o.optionID
                                       and  v.valueID   = o.valueID
group by v.variantID
having count(*) = (select count(*) from OptionValueList )
```

Comment: I could not understand the top of your code, but the query you wrote at the bottom Works. Thank you!

Comment: `declare @t OptionValueList
insert into @t (OptionID,ValueID,ProductID) values(16,1,319),(17,4,319)
select  v.variantID
from    tbl_VariantValues v
        inner join @t o on v.productID = o.productID and v.optionID = o.optionID
                                       and  v.valueID = o.valueID
group by v.variantID
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @t)`

Comment: I mean, above part

Comment: that part is just for me to create the sample data which i don't have. For you, only required `the query` and replace the table variable with your actual table name